# Imagick and rmagick blocking rails server to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick, imagick

i installed ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 than uninstall it than i install  ImageMagick 6.7.6.3 but its still taking old one so how can i resolve this problem and if i wanna install all the gems again so what i have to do to install it again

```
 /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick2.so: This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.7.6 but ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 is in use. (RuntimeError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/lib/RMagick.rb:11
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff/base.rb:2
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff.rb:25
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff.rb:5:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/gruff-0.3.6/lib/gruff.rb:5
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /home/paladion/project/new-sprint/sprint-19/config/application.rb:14
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Comment: please format your code yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need reinstall rmagick with your current imagemagick

```
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: have your several image magick install on your server ? Can you delete old one ?>

Comment: ya i wanna delete old one but how can i do this?

Comment: i uninstalled it and again install correct version but its not working its taking old one only how can i remove all that and install it again correctly i follow the step present in this blog   http://openrails.blogspot.in/2010/12/install-image-magick-and-rmagick-for.html